# Insert element to list based on previous and next elements

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to add a new tuple to a list of tuples (sorted by first element in tuple), where the new tuple contains elements from both the previous and the next element in the list.

Example:

```
oldList = [(3, 10), (4, 7), (5,5)]
newList = [(3, 10), (4, 10), (4, 7), (5, 7), (5, 5)]
```

(4,10) was constructed from and added in between (3,**10**) and (**4**,7).

```
Construct (x,y) from (a,y) and (x,b)
```

I've tried using enumerate() to insert at the specific position, but that doesn't really let me access the next element.

Comment: What is the user's input? the new position of the new elm?

Comment: The user only provides the initial "oldList". Then in between each 2 old elements, a new element is added based on the two existing ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
oldList = [(3, 10), (4, 7), (5,5)]

def pair(lst):
    # create two iterators
    it1, it2 = iter(lst), iter(lst)
    # move second to the second tuple
    next(it2)
    for ele in it1:
        # yield original
        yield ele
        # yield first ele from next and first from current
        yield (next(it2)[0], ele[1])
```

Which will give you:

```
In [3]: oldList = [(3, 10), (4, 7), (5, 5)]

In [4]: list(pair(oldList))
Out[4]: [(3, 10), (4, 10), (4, 7), (5, 7), (5, 5)]
```

Obviously we need to do some error handling to handle different possible situations.

You could also do it using a single iterator if you prefer:

```
def pair(lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    prev = next(it)
    for ele in it:
        yield prev
        yield (prev[0], ele[1])
        prev = ele
    yield (prev[0], ele[1])
```

You can use [itertools.tee](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) in place of calling iter:

```
from itertools import tee
def pair(lst):
    # create two iterators
    it1, it2 = tee(lst)
    # move second to the second tuple
    next(it2)
    for ele in it1:
        # yield original
        yield ele
        # yield first ele from next and first from current
        yield (next(it2)[0], ele[1])
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this works like a charm. While it functions for my current list, how would error handling improve this method?

Comment: @SilviuTofan, really just things like catching empty/single tuples etc.. how you handle it  it would depend on what you want to happen in those situations

Answer (score 5):

You can use a list comprehension and `itertools.chain()`:

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable([((i, j), (x, j)) for (i, j), (x, y) in zip(oldList, oldList[1:])])) + oldList[-1:]
[(3, 10), (4, 10), (4, 7), (5, 7), (5, 5)]
```

Comment: Thank you also for your answer! I only got around to implementing the other one as it was posted slightly earlier than yours.

Answer (score 3):

Not being a big fan of one-liners (or complexity) myself, I will propose a very explicit and readable (which is usually a good thing!) solution to your problem.

So, **in a very simplistic approach**, you could do this:

```
def insertElements(oldList):
    """
    Return a new list, alternating oldList tuples with 
    new tuples in the form (oldList[i+1][0],oldList[i][1])
    """
    newList = []
    for i in range(len(oldList)-1):
      # take one tuple as is
      newList.append(oldList[i])
      # then add a new one with items from current and next tuple
      newList.append((oldList[i+1][0],oldList[i][1]))
    else:
      # don't forget the last tuple
      newList.append(oldList[-1])
    return newList

oldList = [(3, 10), (4, 7), (5, 5)]
newList = insertElements(oldList)
```

That will give you the desired result in `newList`:

```
print(newList)
[(3, 10), (4, 10), (4, 7), (5, 7), (5, 5)]
```

This is not much longer code than other more sophisticated (and memory efficient!) solutions, like using generators, AND I consider it a lot easier to read than intricate one-liners. Also, it would be easy to add some checks to this simple function (like making sure you have a list of tuples).

Unless you already know you need to optimize this particular piece of your code (assuming this is part of a bigger project), this should be [good enough](https://youtu.be/gHG9FRSlPxw). At the same time it is: easy to implement, easy to read, easy to explain, easy to maintain, easy to extend, easy to refactor, etc.

**Note**: all other previous answers to your question are also better solutions than this simple one, in many ways. Just wanted to give you another choice. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate this answer as well, it makes for a very easy to read and easy to implement piece of code!